# Replacing the strings in list/dataframe column in python by comparison

Tags: python, pandas, string, data-science

I have the following dataframe column

```
Hotels
Hotel Tulsi Viha
Hotel Tulsi Vih
Hotel Tulsi Vihar
SWIGGYBang
Swiggy
Borivali Biryani center
Borivali Biryani centr
```

I want to check for string similarity and replace it:-
For eg Hotel Tulsi Vih, Hotel Tulsi Viha, Hotel Tulsi Vihar are same, so I want string "Hotel Tulsi Vihar" that replaces the other 2 strings. Similarly it needs to be done on entire column

Answer (score 1):

You can apply [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/) library to check the similar string.

For example, you have a main list

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process, fuzz

main_list = ['Hotel Tulsi Vihar','Swiggy','Borivali Biryani center']

## compare the similar string to a list, as below
process.extract("Hotel Tulsi Viha", main_list , limit=2, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)

## Result -> [('Hotel Tulsi Vihar', 97), ('Swiggy', 18), ('Borivali Biryani center', 15)]
```

So, you can apply this function to a dataframe

```
## Create/Import dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(['Hotels','Hotel Tulsi Viha','Hotel Tulsi Vih','Hotel Tulsi Vihar'\
,'SWIGGYBang','Swiggy','Borivali Biryani center','Borivali Biryani centr'],columns=['Brand'])

## This is example function to compare word with a list and threshold. 
def check_fuzzywuzzy(word, list_unique,threshold):
    highest_pos = process.extract(word, list_unique, limit=1, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
    if highest_pos[0][1] > threshold:
        return highest_pos[0][0]
    else:
        return word

## Apply function
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: check_fuzzywuzzy(x['Brand'], main_list,60), axis=1)

# Result
#                    Brand          new_column_name
#0                   Hotels                   Hotels
#1         Hotel Tulsi Viha        Hotel Tulsi Vihar
#2          Hotel Tulsi Vih        Hotel Tulsi Vihar
#3        Hotel Tulsi Vihar        Hotel Tulsi Vihar
#4               SWIGGYBang                   Swiggy
#5                   Swiggy                   Swiggy
#6  Borivali Biryani center  Borivali Biryani center
#7   Borivali Biryani centr  Borivali Biryani center
```

Then, you can use the new column, or you can apply to the same column, 'Brand'.

For the fuzzywuzzy library, it has several score for checking the similar string, e.g., token_set_ratio, partial_ratio. More information is in this [link](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy).

Comment: I know about fuzzywuzzy, but the main issue here is main_list that you mentioned. I won't have predefined main_list. The example which i gave was based on observation so in actual scenario fetching main_list out of the entire column would be difficult as it data in hotel column would change constantly.

Comment: I think the main_list could be predefined by the column that you want to change. Also, when new data are added, then you can compare it with the current list whether to add a new hotel to the list or not based on a threshold value. I don't sure what do you mean in difficulty. if you mean the computational complexity, I agree that it will have high computational to check the similarity pairwise.